# Макрос __func__

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

Переношу проект на более старые зависимости для поддержки более старых ОС, начиная с `Ｗindows 7`、но тут появляется проблема при переносе, в 2017 версии  я тянул имена функций через макрос __func__, но в 2010 версии мне выдает:

> error C2065: '__func__`' : undeclared identifier

Можно ли как то перенести данный макрос, функций просто нереально большое количество, и переписывание каждого имени отнимет очень большое кол-во времени?

UPD: Забыл предупредить, нужно имя функции без префикса класса. т.е. не `libvlc::get_errmsg` что возвращает макрос __FUNCTION__, а `get_errmsg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте определение

```
#define  __func__  __FUNCTION__
```

и вам не придется менять весь код :) Пока вы работаете в Visual C++ - это безопасное решение. Можете, если опасаетесь, обвязать его для конкретной версии:

```
#if _MSC_VER == 1600
#define  __func__  __FUNCSIG__
#endif
```

В VC++ 2010 нет `__func__`, но есть `__FUNCTION__`.

Более информативна, впрочем, замена

```
#define  __func__  __FUNCSIG__
```

Comment: Все наоборот, в с++ нет `__FUNCTION__`, но есть `__func__`.

Comment: @VTT Тьфу, я имел в виду VC++ 2010... Работаю одновременно на три экрана - вот и сбиваюсь...

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.100).aspx позволяет предположить, что что-нибудь вроде `__FUNCTION__`:

```
// Demonstrates functionality of __FUNCTION__, __FUNCDNAME__, and __FUNCSIG__ macros
void exampleFunction()
{
    printf("Function name: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    printf("Decorated function name: %s\n", __FUNCDNAME__);
    printf("Function signature: %s\n", __FUNCSIG__);

    // Sample Output
    // -------------------------------------------------
    // Function name: exampleFunction
    // Decorated function name: ?exampleFunction@@YAXXZ
    // Function signature: void __cdecl exampleFunction(void)
}
```